# IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier - Keycloak

Tags: asp.net-mvc, keycloak, keycloak-services

I’m currently working on an ASP.NET MVC application (.net framework - 4.5.2) and have integrated Keycloak into my ASP.NET MVC application. When attempting to log in with Keycloak, I encounter the following error message:

[image]

> IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve
> SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier ( IsReadOnly = False,
> Count = 1, Clause[0] =
> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause ) ',
> token:
> '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"d6f986c1-1634-42c3-831c-def9eb705e3d"}.{"exp":1698658811,"iat":1698658511,"auth_time":1698658511,"jti":"a5529aaf-c1e8-4ce8-9fe1-87610e37c82f","iss":"http://localhost:8080/realms/Demo","aud":["TestSSO","account"],"sub":"7f1b6128-2d59-4c75-bf1a-18f978af79b0","typ":"Bearer","azp":"TestSSO","session_state":"64ce271d-3440-4b53-a711-23d00d41f032","acr":"1","allowed-origins":["http://localhost:64346/*"],"realm_access":{"roles":["offline_access","uma_authorization","default-roles-demo"]},"resource_access":{"account":{"roles":["manage-account","manage-account-links","view-profile"]}},"scope":"openid
> email testaudience
> profile","sid":"64ce271d-3440-4b53-a711-23d00d41f032","email_verified":false,"name":"Test
> User","preferred_username":"testuser1","given_name":"Test","family_name":"User","email":"mtech.navi@gmail.com"}'.

This is what I have so far,

```
    app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions{        
                ClientId = "TestSSO",
                ClientSecret = "ZVqHv3H5a4NrsHPdho8ki5pYKzEYKJg9",               
                Realm = "Demo",
                KeycloakUrl = "http://localhost:8080/",
                AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType, 
                DisableTokenSignatureValidation = true,
                DisableAudienceValidation = true
            });
```

I made several attempt to resolve this. But I could not fix the issue. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance.